# Save Entity (which contains another Entity) from JSON

Tags: json, spring-mvc, knockout.js, spring-roo

**Background:**

I'm making pages with JSON-based CRUD functionality. These pages feature select lists populated with my entities via Knockout.js. I have one entity `Contract` that has a currently nullable many-to-one relationship `contractHolder` with another of my entities, `Organization`.

I can successfully create a `Contract` via JSON through my Roo-generated controller, as long as `contractHolder` is null.

My attempts to create a `Contract` with a non-null relationship end in errors, regardless of whether I provide an integer ID (java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.util.Map) or a full JSON object (org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance).

All told, I am trying to save a `Contract` with an `contractHolder` determined by select list.

**Contract.java**

```
public class Contract {
    /* ... */

    //@NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    private Organization contractHolder;

    /* ... */
}
```

**Organization.java**

```
public class Organization {
    /* ... */

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Forget about the acronyms for awhile and first go to json.org and learn the JSON syntax.  Then study the Java Map and List interface definitions and understand how they map to JSON "objects" and "arrays".

Comment: @HotLicks Thanks for your quick comment! I can successfully get everything deserialized and back into my objects, but I trip up at the very end.

Comment: I don't know what JSON kit you're using (there are at least 20 for Java), but your errors suggest you have some basic misconceptions.  (And you've not provided anywhere near enough info to be a valid "question" here.)

Comment: I found that my basic misconceptions were of Hibernate. Would you recommend I add more information to my question, answer my question, or something else entirely?

Comment: Write a brief answer that explains the source of your misconceptions.  After the (I think 3-day) waiting period, mark that answer "accepted".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, my issue was with Hibernate. In trying to create my Contract with a non-null contractHolder, I correctly described the Organization but failed to account for the fact that it doesn't exist in the session.

```
org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: 
    object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.domain.application.model.Contract.contractHolder -> com.domain.application.model.Organization;
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
    org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: 
        object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.domain.application.model.Contract.contractHolder -> com.domain.application.model.Organization
```

To solve this, I have taken the time to refresh associated objects.

Part of my deserialization process for Contract is replacing the associated entities with their newly-retrieved-from-database selves.